# Composer Update in Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have cloned a laravel project into linux server.
After running "Composer Update" the process stucks on "updating dependencies" and never goes on for hours.
Please any help. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Usually, it could help to update Composer itself or tighten the version constraints (having them too open means heavy work for the dependency resolver)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Trying to remove the vendor folder or renamed it. And then run command "Composer Install".
and checked the laravel logs or Apache logs for more info and post here what you see errors

Comment: Running `composer install` instead of `composer update`  makes a huge difference

Comment: Additionally, neither the logs of Laravel or Apache contain any information about the progress of `composer update`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming after you cloned it (via git) to your new server you have to

```
composer install
```

The dependencies.